# LaravelCollective/html escape inconsistency with double curly braces

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

On Laravel 5.8 I can use double curly braces to escape a string `{{ "<script>alert('does not work');</script>" }}` or a variable `{{ $comment }}`

However, if I use LaravelCollective/html package to create html elements, double curly braces doesn't escape anything. `{{ Form::input('edit', 'test') }}` creates an input.

How does LaravelCollective/html achieve this or is this an exception in Blade syntax itself? Is `{{ }}` a secure way to escape anything if it's sometimes escaped and sometimes not? Could I make a custom class to fool Laravel into thinking I'm using LaravelCollective/html and get unescaped content printed with the custom class/object with `{{ }}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems LaravelCollective/html achieves this by registering a custom handler with `BladeCompiler::directive()`, so it's an extension feature provided by Blade. As such it's safe to use `{{ }}` for both escaping and creating html elements with LaravelCollective.

For reference, here's a snippet from HtmlServiceProvider.php in LaravelCollective/Html for how it's done.

```
/**
 * Register Blade directives.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function registerBladeDirectives()
{
    $this->app->afterResolving('blade.compiler', function (BladeCompiler $bladeCompiler) {
        $namespaces = [
            'Html' => get_class_methods(HtmlBuilder::class),
            'Form' => get_class_methods(FormBuilder::class),
        ];

        foreach ($namespaces as $namespace => $methods) {
            foreach ($methods as $method) {
                if (in_array($method, $this->directives)) {
                    $snakeMethod = Str::snake($method);
                    $directive = strtolower($namespace).'_'.$snakeMethod;

                    $bladeCompiler->directive($directive, function ($expression) use ($namespace, $method) {
                        return "<?php echo $namespace::$method($expression); ?>";
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```